# adding year to date format %a,%d/%m

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to scrape a table from this website:
https://www.epexspot.com/en/market-data/capacitymarket/capacity-table/

`table = pd.read_html("https://www.epexspot.com/en/market-data/capacitymarket")[0]`

Here's the output it gives:
[image]

I want to change the columns to the format %y-%m-%d. The columns for the above table should be 
 `2018-09-13, 2018-10-18, 2018-12-13, 2019-03-21, 2019-05-15, 2019-06-27, 2019-09-12`

Any suggestion?

Comment: what is the original table data? I cannot access the homepage.

Comment: @Lamanus Can you access this page? https://www.epexspot.com/en/market-data/capacitymarket/capacity-table/

Comment: Oh, you want to change the header format not a column, right?

Comment: @Lamanus yes, I will edit in my question

Answer (score 1):

By iterating over `table.columns` and using `datetime` module. Just make sure to use `replace(year=2019)` otherwise the default year (1900) will be used.

```
from datetime import datetime

table.columns = [datetime.strptime(column, '%a, %d/%m').replace(year=2019).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                 if '/' in column else column for column in table.columns]
```

You can use `map` if you don't like the long list comprehension:

```
def rename_col(col):
    if '/' in col:
        return datetime.strptime(col, '%a, %d/%m').replace(year=2019).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return col

table.columns = map(rename_col, table.columns)
```

Comment: I have both 2018 and 2019 years in the columns. "Thu,13/12" is the mark for the year transition

Comment: This solution will fail on Feb 29 (leap year). Use instead: `datetime.strptime("{}.{}".format(col,year), '%a, %d/%m.%Y')`